# Randomized function: Prevent the previous result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with a randomized result like that:

```
 document.getElementById('recaller').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10) % randomStrings.length - 1);
            newText1 = randomStrings[randomIndex];
            newText2 = randomStrings2[randomIndex];
            answer2.innerHTML = newText2;
        });
```

and the content from here:

```
var randomStrings2 = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5"
];
```

Correctly, sometimes within the randomized function the result is the same within 2 "clicks". How can I prevent, that the previous result gets shown in the next clicks' try?

To visualize I don't want that result: 1,1,2,2,1,3...

But of course that result would be alright 1,2,3,1,2,4,5,1...

Comment: I got more output wihtin the function, but corrected things within the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the old value and then repeat your function to calculate the function until they are not the same.

```
        document.getElementById('recaller').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var lastValue = answer2.innerHTML;
            do{
            var randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10) % randomStrings.length - 1);
            newText1 = randomStrings[randomIndex];
            newText2 = randomStrings2[randomIndex];
            answer2.innerHTML = newText2;
            } while(lastValue == answer2.innerHTML);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store your result in a variable and compare this variable with your result. Like so :

```
let savedNumber = 999;
const getRandomNumber = () => { return Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10) % randomStrings.length - 1) };

document.getElementById('recaller').addEventListener('click', function() {
            let randomIndex;
            while ((randomIndex = getRandomNumber()) == savedNumber)
                ;  
            savedNumber = randomIndex;
            newText1 = randomStrings[randomIndex];
            newText2 = randomStrings2[randomIndex];
            answer2.innerHTML = newText2;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n=0;
var randomStrings = [1,2,3,4,5];
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
var lastEl=array[array.length-1];
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  if(lastEl===array[0])shuffle(array);
  
  return array;
}
document.getElementById('recaller').addEventListener('click', function() {
if(n===randomStrings.length){randomStrings=shuffle(randomStrings);n=0;}
          newText1 = randomStrings[n];
          n++;
            document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML += newText1+'\n';
        });
```

```html
<input type="button" id='recaller' value="generate random value">
<div style="display: inline-block" id="answer2">--</div>
```